# How to correctly edit vbproj file in VS2015 for incorrect nuget package information

Tags: visual-studio

We have a project that is housed in Visual Studio Online and we're trying to deploy it to Azure.  When the build executed, we got an error about a missing nuget package.  In VS, nuget did report that a package was missing and I restored it but we continue to get an error in VSO (the app compiles without error and if I deploy directly from VS to Azure, it works).

So I opened the vbproj file and in the last section, I see this:

```
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
<PropertyGroup>
  <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
</PropertyGroup>
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\theprojectfolder\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\SMDTalentLink\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\theprojectfolder\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\SMDTalentLink\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props'))" />
```

While the package has been restored, it seems that VS hasn't deleted the error.  VSO sees the error and won't compile the package.  Can I delete this or do I need to edit it somehow?  I'm not familiar with the proj files and am afraid I'll make things worse.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the items does fix the issue.  Unclear why VS didn't fix it.